# Function mapping JavaScript builtin class to html tag name

Tags: javascript

I need a function that maps JavaScript builtin class to corresponding html tag name, e.g.:

```
function classToTagName(clazz) {
  // implementation
}

classToTagName(HTMLInputElement) // ->
"input" 
classToTagName(HTMLAnchorElement) // ->
"a"
```

Is it possible to implement it without using explicit mapping or regex?

I could use DOM `tagName` property if I had object instance, but browsers seem to prohibit invoking constructors of builtin tag classes with `TypeError: Illegal constructor`.

Comment: I was more wondering how you were getting this interface name. I didn't know if there would be a way to use some other data to get the tag name or is something providing you only the interface class name?

Comment: Yeah, what's the big picture you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create web components with es6 classes - `class SuperInput extends HTMLInputElement {}`. I'm lazy and I want to write `register(SuperInput)` instead of `document.registerElement('super-input', { prototype: SuperInput.prototype, extends: 'input'});`. I need `classToTagName` to implement register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such mapping, as an interface can belong to multiple tag names. Here is a (possibly not complete) list of ambiguous interfaces (based on the [element list on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)):

```
HTMLElement: address,article,aside,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section,dd,dt,figcaption,figure,main,abbr,b,bdi,bdo,cite,code,dfn,em,i,kbd,mark,rp,ruby,rt,rtc,rb,s,samp,small,strong,sub,sup,u,var,wbr,noscript,summary,acronym,basefont,big,center,command,noembed,plaintext,strike,tt
HTMLHeadingElement: h1,h6,h2,h3,h4,h5
HTMLPreElement: pre,listing,xmp
HTMLUnknownElement: data,time,menuitem,element,applet,blink,isindex,multicol,nextid,spacer
HTMLQuoteElement: q,blockquote
HTMLModElement: del,ins
HTMLTableColElement: col,colgroup
HTMLTableSectionElement: tbody,thead,tfoot
HTMLTableCellElement: td,th
```

Comment: Best example that shows there is no point implementing such a function. Thanks.

Comment: FYI the list Chrome uses is generated from metadata, [HTMLNames.in](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/html/HTMLTagNames.in?q=HTMLTagNames.in&sq=package:chromium&l=1). If an entry doesn't have an interfaceName line, the interface name is HTML(Thing)Element. If you poke around the Chromium tree you'll see Python scripts that process this file. WebKit (Safari) has something similar.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Custom Elements](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/),

> When defining our custom element, we have to also specify the extends option:
>
> ```
> customElements.define("plastic-button", PlasticButton, { extends: "button" });
> ```

The spec editors already know that may seem redundant information, but they explain:

> In general, the name of the element being extended cannot be
>   determined simply by looking at what element interface it extends, as
>   many elements share the same interface (such as `q` and `blockquote`
>   both sharing `HTMLQuoteElement`).

So it's not possible. Your mapping is not well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not exactly the mapping you were asking about, but hope it helps.

```js
const getInterfaceName = e => Object.getPrototypeOf(e).constructor.name;
const createElement = tag => document.createElement(tag);
const getTagInterface = tag => getInterfaceName(createElement(tag));

console.log(getTagInterface('a'));  // HTMLAnchorElement 
console.log(getTagInterface('input'));  // HTMLInputElement
```

You can get the name of the interface by looking up the element's proto chain at the constructor function's name.

Comment: @Oriol no, local name returns `input` which is what we started with.

Comment: @Oriol also changed __proto__ to Object.getPrototypeOf, thanks for the tip.